# Property must be marked as readonly after save

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

In .net Core 5.0 I have the following model class:

```
 public class Player
 {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

My Context looks like this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().Property(p => p.Id)
            .UseIdentityColumn()
            .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```

However, when I try to add a migration, I get the following error:

> The property 'Player.Id' must be marked as read-only after it has been
> saved because it is part of a key. Key properties are always read-only
> once an entity has been saved for the first time.

Playing around with the setter and/or marking properties as readonly does not solve anything.
Any clues where this behavior comes from and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#value-generation) "..., a numeric primary key in SQL Server is automatically set up to be an IDENTITY column."

Try removing the DataGenerated annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error in dotnet 6 (EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.3).

The solution for me is the following.

Change

```
.Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore)
```

to

```
.Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Throw)
```

and do the same change for every table in the database definitions.